# APEX - switch item - modify report

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a set of switch items (yes,no) which **should** result in a modified report when clicked.

Simplified setup: Button1, Dynamic Report

PL/SQL query from dynamic report

```
declare
q_query varchar2(500);
q_select varchar2(500);
q_where varchar2(500);

begin
q_select := 'select Kat1, Kat2, Kat3 from TBL ';

IF :Button1 = '1' THEN
q_where := 'where Kat3=KatXYZ';
END IF;

q_query := q_select||q_where;

return q_query;
end;
```

FYI

- Kat3 contains strings
- KatXYZ is the string to search for
- The query (select ... from ... when Kat3='KatXYZ';) works when
  changing to SQL instead of PL/SQL
- Dynamic Event created for Button1 to refresh report on change
- q_where := 'where Kat3="KatXYZ"'; does not work
- Button1 Custom Settings On Value: 1 - Off Value: 0

Problem: Nothing happens when clicking the switch item "Yes". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
q_where := 'where Kat3=KatXYZ';
```

says that column `Kat3` should be equal to column/parameter/function named `KatXYZ`, not **string** `'KatXYZ'`.

Try with

```
q_where := 'where Kat3 = ''KatXYZ''';
```

or

```
q_where := 'where Kat3 = ' || chr(39) || 'KatXYZ' || chr(39);
```

or

```
q_where := q['where Kat3 = 'KatXYZ']'
```

Any of those should be OK.